# How to handle subflows

Tags: spring-integration

Can we use somehow "subflows" in Spring Integration?

I have many different processes which would use the same "subflow".  These processes have always the same part which would be good to be put into a separate file.

What would be the corrent way to implement these flows?

I tried to find a solution to use subflows in Spring Integration but I could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple technique is to put the subflow in a separate file with "well-known" input and output channels (the subflow starts with one channel and ends with another). Then, simply `<import/>` the subflow and send/consume to/from the input/output channel.

Or, instead of an import you can use the [Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl) to define the subflow and add it to your application contexts that need the subflow...

```
@Configuration
public class MySubflowDefinition {

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow subflow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("someInChannel")
           .transform(...)
           ...
           .channel("someOutChannel")
           .get();
    }
}
```

For a more formal "subflow" definition, see the [spring-integration-flow extension](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-flow). This solution also allows the same subflow to be invoked from multiple places in the same application context.

`spring-integration-java-dsl` and `spring-integration-flow` are both available in the spring repo and maven central with (currently) versions 1.0.0.RELEASE.

Comment: If you want to use the same subflow in more than one place in the __same__ application context, you would need to use the `spring-integration-flow` solution.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.
Do these solutions also work when you want to use the subflow in more than one places?

Let's say we have Subflow1 which originally aimed to transfer FTP files from source directory to destination directory. 

Now we have 3 different (main)flows where I want to use this Subflow1 with different parameters like FTP server address / destination directories.

Can I do it with your suggestion?
How would it work? Let's say there is a File 'F' in the FTP directory 'D'. All the main flows which use this subflow will receive the same packages?