# How to handle subflows that is packaged in separate jar

Tags: spring-integration

I have four subflows each sitting in its own application and packaged in jar file.
Each subflow is build as spring boot application. 
Each subflow has input channel and output channel.

I would like the to have the main flow sitting in its own spring-boot application that will sequentially called those 4 subflows. 
Is it possible with spring integration?
If it is not possible what would be the best approach that is possible?
I searched the internet and look at 
[How to handle subflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306239/how-to-handle-subflows)
 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-flow 
and everything else that I can find but still not sure how to proceed. 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-flow states that to use subflow I need to have in my xml
`int-flow:flow id="subflow1"` 
How do I tie this subflow1 to my subflow packaged in the separate jar. 
Then how would I invoke this subflows in my main flow that is spring boot application? 
Do I sent message to the input channel to each subflow to start subflow or do something else?
Thanks,David

Example of subflow xml file.
 I removed irrelevant parts of the file to shorten it and put ... in place of removed info

```
 <int:channel id="createTwo"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="createOne" output-channel="createTwo"        
     ref="automationUtilities" method="createTwo"/>         
...

<int:service-activator input-channel="createFive"         
     ref="automationUtilities" method="createSix"/>                                     

<bean id="automationUtilities" class="package.BeanName" />
<bean id="validator" class="package.anotherBeanName" />
<util:properties id="config" location="classpath:application.properties"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your applications are Spring Boot, then they are Microservices and each of them lives in its onw JVM. Therefore just having `input` and `output` channel isn't enough. Because you can't just send message from one JVM to another.

Since all of them are Spring Boot, consider to add some REST capabilities for them. At least simple `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` to receive messages from external world. And `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` to perform REST request from one application to another.

OTOH consider to use [Spring Cloud Stream](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/) project, which is founded exactly for Messaging Microservices communication. It is based on the `Binder` concept, currently Kafka or RabbitMQ.